# What to do after LASSO coefs are all 0?

Tags: feature-selection, lasso

I am doing variable selection on a `p > n` data by LASSO. The LASSO coefs are all 0. I am not sure what to do next.

I understand that LASSO find it is not worth to increase the coefs.

What should I check? What directions should I look into?

n = 100, and p = 1000.

I use `glmnet` library. `cv.glmnet(x_train,y_train,alpha=1)`

Comment: I think you're going to have to give us more information about the data and how you're doing the LASSO. It seems strange that it would force all coefficients to zero unless your tuning parameter was really high.

Comment: There could be a number of reasons all the coef.'s drop to zero: Perhaps none of the covariates you've included are predictors in the optimal lasso model, or your sample size is very small, or there's a lot of noise in your data masking associations, or the effect sizes of the covariates are very small.

Comment: @Sullysaurus the $\lambda` is chosed automatically by `glmnet`

Comment: You could try a $\lambda$ sequence that includes more values at the smaller end; it's possible that the minimum of the default method GLMNET provides is too large.

Comment: If possible, collecting more data wouldn't be a bad idea - especially given you have 10 times more variables than observations.